# Number each sheet based on its order

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I want the put a number in the header of each sheet depending on what order it comes in.

I have a user form(Numberbox) where the person puts in a starting number.

So if the starting number is 3, and there are 5 sheets...from left to right the headers should be 3, 4, 5,6,7,8.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the Header? a cell? the Sheet name?

Comment: The header is a combination ..part of a more complicated macro I have. This is the last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of the worksheets object matches the order of the sheets, so you can just loop through the sheets:

```
For i = 1 to Worksheets.Count
    Worksheets(i).PageSetup.CenterHeader = frmUserForm.NumberBox.Value + i - 1
Next i
```